# Back to Top Button

Tags: feature-request, design

Can we get **Back to Top Button** on [Top Question Page](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [All Question Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest&pagesize=50)?

The reason behind this request is sometimes I scroll down the questions to see the available questions that I can answer, when the scroll bar already on the bottom page I want to refresh the page to find the newest questions. When the whole page already load, the page will display on the latest state (in this case my scroll bar on the bottom page). So when I want to go to top page I must scroll back to the top, maybe if this possible added some button in the right corner like in [9gag](http://9gag.com).

Comment: There are a number of browser extensions/add-ons that can do this for you. In Firefox I use "Scroll to Top/Bottom". In Chrome I use "Scroll to Top Button".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are at a PC, then press <kbd>home</kbd> and you will magically be back to the top of the page. Not sure we need to duplicate browser functionality.

Equally, using <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to scroll up/down may save you some time - again, standard browser shortcuts (nothing to do with stackoverflow).

Comment: After I tried your suggestion there is no need for this Back to the top button. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then what's the need in having mouse if you can use `Tab` and `Enter` to navigate hyperlinks? FWIW, most people use keyboard shortcuts with their left hands, holding mouse in the right hand. It is terribly inconvenient to use `Home` key while surfing the net: some cross, some switch their hands. I'd go for having `Top` button, I see no harm for UI in it.

Comment: "Not sure we need to duplicate browser functionality." Don't know what browser you're using, but mine doesn't have any functionality that brings me to the top of a page. My _keyboard_ has that functionality though.

Comment: @j08691 no, it is definitely the browser application that does this. Your keyboard, by itself, is just plastic. Quibbling over whether you use a mouse, keyboard, eye gestures, or mind control - doesn't change that this is still a browser feature

Comment: Until eye gestures and mind control replace my keyboard, it's still the way the "press home" you referenced works. I can't "press home" on my browser but I can on my keyboard. Also, what about if I'm on a tablet? There's no "home" key to press or any similar function that in one touch or click brings me back to the top. I think a back to top link in the footer is small, unobtrusive, and highly functional.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the refresh to scroll to the top, use the keyboard shortcuts in Marc's answer.

If you want the button to scroll to the top so that you can see the top again, for whatever reason, why not *scroll manually*? Just click the scrollbar and drag it to the top--it takes about a second.

9gag has infinite scrolling, which is why that button is implemented. We've got a relatively tiny page--just scroll to the top normally.

I have no official say, but I really want to post this pic *somewhere*:

[image: enter link description here]

(That's [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver), SE dev)

Anyway, that's what I think will happen here ;-)

Comment: if you just refresh, most browsers will refresh but take you back to the same place, i.e. you won't see the fresh content (which is at the top).

Comment: @MarcGravell: Oh, right... One sec, will edit out.