# Add top link on the bottom only on Mobile

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

I request a top ( ^ ) link to be available on the bottom (near paging links) **only  on Mobile site**.

It will be used when scroll down until last question in page.

It'll be useful mainly when loading 50 per page.

This isn't a duplicate for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314131/add-a-back-to-top-link) which is about adding it to **left navigation bar**

This isn't an exact duplicate for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134553/back-to-top-button) which is about adding it on browser, becauase my main issue is on **mobile** browsing

Comment: I assume this would mostly be useful on phones etc, which don't have easy access to the Home key.

Comment: @NathanTuggy you are right

Comment: SOX (Stack Overflow Extras), available on stackapps, has an option to enable this.

Comment: Regarding duplicate appeal, it doesn't really matter where the link is placed. The core idea is the same: have a "back to top" link.

Comment: @Shadow The other question specifically asks to put it in the left nav, which is collapsed on mobile viewports, plus on desktops where the user has chosen to hide it.

Comment: @Sonic this question says "mainly on Mobile". It's not enough to make it non duplicate plus, pointless. Code don't understand "mainly". Either there is "back to top" link, or there isn't. So unless this question is edited to say "**only** in mobile device", I won't cast a reopen vote.

Comment: @ShadowWizard update question for mobile only

Comment: Cheers, reopened it.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, you can just [tap the status bar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619421-scrollstotop?language=objc) and the screen will scroll to the top. This works in surprisingly many apps, including Safari, Chrome, and also the Stack Exchange mobile app.

Comment: Mobile app isn't relevant, question is about using a browser on mobile device, as far as I can see. Does this trick work with Chrome too? Think it's the most popular non-builtin browser.

Comment: Yeah, you have to do development work to *disable* this feature, so most apps support it, including Chrome.